# Combining polygon datasets

Tags: qgis, postgis

I need to combine 2 large polygon datasets. One of these datasets contains more recent data, so the polygons from this dataset need to be copied into the existing dataset.

There are three different instances where the existing dataset would need to be modified. See below for screenshots and explanations.

(In all screenshots the dashed red outline represents the existing data. The green polygons are new data.)

---

**Situation 1** - Entirely new polygon:

[image]

**Action** - New polygon needs to be added to existing dataset. Polygons that remain the same can be ignored.

---

**Situation 2** - An existing polygon has changed shape:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Action** - Existing polygon(s) needs to be deleted. New polygon then needs to be added to existing dataset.

---

**Situation 3** - Multiple new polygons within an existing polygon

[image]

**Action** - Existing containing/large polygon needs to be deleted. New polygon then needs to be added to existing dataset.

---

So, my question is; would it be possible to combine these datasets according to the rules above, either in QGIS or PostGIS?

Comment: Are you apposed to using a different process for each situation.

Comment: @Kingfisher Yes I was thinking that might be necessary... Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: How do we know if the polygon is new? You're providing graphics, how about a table definition? Paste the output of `\d table`

Comment: @Evan there is nothing currently in the tables to indicate new/old polygons, but it would be simple to add something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can do all of this in 2 steps. First, delete all existing polygons where the new polygons table intersects them. In case 1, the existing polygons will not be touched. In cases 2 and 3, all existing polygons that have either grown (and possibly merged into one) or shrunk (and possibly split into smaller ones) will be deleted. Then you simply insert the new polygons into the existing table which will cover cases 2 and 3.

```
DELETE FROM existing_polygons a USING new_polygons b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);

INSERT INTO existing_polygons 
SELECT * FROM new_polygons;
```

Comment: Thanks @John, I think you could well be right with this... I'll give it a try

Comment: You'd better make a copy of the existing polygons table first :-)

Comment: Is this working? I'm reasonably sure the logic is correct, but I'd be interested to know if I've missed something.

Comment: It did work well, apart from a few polygons deleted that needed to be kept (but that was only due to messy data), and relatively easily fixed. Thanks John.

Comment: I'm glad. I hope you had a back up of the data. I felt that such nice diagrams deserved a more complex answer, but sometimes things that look complicated aren't. Sadly, the opposite is also very true.